# ksqldb table does not return expected data

Tags: join, apache-kafka, ksqldb

I created a table from a Kafka topic then I wanted to join a stream with a table but the table is empty and the result of the join is empty. My Kafka topic has some data and the stream on the topic works, but I can not see any data in the table.

```
CREATE TABLE book (
  ID int PRIMARY KEY,
  title varchar(50) ) WITH (
  kafka_topic = 'books.story',
  value_format = 'avro');
```

I have a stream

```
CREATE STREAM store WITH (
  kafka_topic = 'store.hafez',
  value_format = 'avro');
```

Now I want to join this stream and table:

```
CREATE STREAM stories As
  select * from store AS st
  left join book AS bs
  on bs.ID = st.BookID;
```

I can not see any record in the stories stream which contains the data from the table whereas I am sure it should have some data from this side.

Comment: "stream on the topic works" - Then create the table from the stream? Can you please show a [mcve] ? We don't know what data in your topic looks like to know if the table is valid... Are you producing new events after making the table?

Comment: Actually, I want to join a stream with the complete table from the beginning in the result it doesn't return any data although it should have data. Also, when I query select * from book where ID = 1 the table doesn't show anything but has some records in the topic.

Comment: Did you set `auto.offset.reset=earliest`?

Comment: yes I set this parameter before creating the table and stream but the result of joining is still empty

Answer (score 0):

When I created a table, the new records in the topic didn't update the table, so the join result, especially the inner join, didn't return anything. So I created a stream instead of a table and as I wanted to join all records in the books I set the window of the stream to join within 100 days then it worked.

```
CREATE STREAM stories As
   select * from store AS st
   left join book AS bs
   within 100 days
   on bs.ID = st.BookID;
```